# Change background image of CSS class in javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I have this javascript code to increase and decrease the height of div. Function calls on `onclick` event div text changes to 'click to minimize' and if clicked again,it changes to 'click to read'.
I want to change background-image instead of text in `button` class.

```
function chk()
{
    var node = document.getElementById('content');

    node.classList.toggle('expand');
    document.getElementByClass('button').style.backgroundImage = node.classList.contains('expand')? 'click to minimize':'click to read';
}
```

this is the css

```
.content
{
    height:auto;
}

.content.expand
{
    height:150px;
}
```

Comment: Any chance you could post a <www.jsfiddle.net> or a <www.jsbin.com> example so that we could help troubleshoot?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the same method you used for the `#content` element.

CSS:

```
.button {
    background-image: url(xxx.png);
}
.button.alt {
    background-image: url(yyy.png);
}
```

JS:

```
function chk()
{
    var node = document.getElementById('content');
    node.classList.toggle('expand');

    var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('button');
    for(var i=0;i<buttons.length;i++){
       buttons[i].classList.toggle('alt');
    }    
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me if i want to make content div a class and then works same?

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div class="content"></div>
<button onclick="chk(this)">click to read</button>
```

**CSS**

```
.content {
    height:50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color:red;
}
.content.expand {
    height:150px;
}
```

**JS**

```
function chk(e) {
    var node = document.getElementsByClassName('content')[0];
    e.innerHTML = node.className.indexOf('expand') > -1 ?'click to read': 'click to minimize';
    node.className = node.className.indexOf('expand') > -1 ? "content" : "content expand";
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4tvTh/5/)**

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using two different classes (or standard button and an extra class) in your css just to have one central point to define your background-images. something like

```
button {
  background-image: url();
}

button.active {
  background-image: url();
}
```

and then modify your js so that it just toggles the class on those items. Using jQuery this is pretty easy

```
$('button').click(function(){$(this).toggleClass('active')});
```

but standard-JS versions are possible too of course. They just need some if-else clause asking if the class exists or not.

Comment: Of course you have to add two different urls in the CSS and include jQuery if you want to use my code... Any errors thrown?